# While loop that adds additional terms to a function

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a while-loop that adds additional terms to a function. My problem is that whenever I try to add to the function using a while-loop, it does not store the variables in the function as numeric values but as slots.

This is my code:

```
x <- function(r){}
i <- 1
s <- c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04)
C <- 5
NV <- 100
while(i < length(s)){
  x <- function(r){
  x + C/(1+r)^i
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not changing anything inside you loop. You just redefining the function `x`.
If you want to add elements to `x`  you don't need a loop in R.
You can use

```
sum(C / (1+r)^(1:length(s))
```